# How to debug rsyslog on centos7

Tags: linux, debugging, centos7, rsyslog

I have a forward mechanism of rsyslogs to an external service.

Under `/etc/rsyslog.d` I have created a .conf file.

This is the file:

```
$ModLoad imfile
$InputFilePollInterval 1
$InputFileName /var/log/secure
$InputFileTag securelogs:
$InputFileStateFile securelogs
$InputFileFacility local0
$InputRunFileMonitor
:syslogtag, isequal, "securelogs:" {
  :msg, contains, "sshd" {
    local0.* /var/log/forward_securelogs_audit.log
    local0.* @@<server-ip>:514
  }
  stop
}
```

I have the same configurations on multiple servers, but for 2 of them, it is not working.

How can I debug?

I tried following the instructions here - https://www.rsyslog.com/how-to-use-debug-on-demand/

But there is no file  - `/etc/rc.d/init.d/rsyslog`

Also there is no file - `/var/run/rsyslogd.pid`

When fetching the version `rsyslogd -v` I get the following

```
0726.220297821:7f4d57c22780: Note: debug on demand turned on via configuraton file, use USR1 signal to activate.
rsyslogd 8.24.0-57.el7_9, compiled with:
        PLATFORM:                               x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu
        PLATFORM (lsb_release -d):
        FEATURE_REGEXP:                         Yes
        GSSAPI Kerberos 5 support:              Yes
        FEATURE_DEBUG (debug build, slow code): No
        32bit Atomic operations supported:      Yes
        64bit Atomic operations supported:      Yes
        memory allocator:                       system default
        Runtime Instrumentation (slow code):    No
        uuid support:                           Yes
        Number of Bits in RainerScript integers: 64
```

But again, I cannot see anything in the debug file, nor on the terminal.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The document you link to is very old, and RedHat and CentOS now use systemd to start the daemon so those files no longer exist. If you do

```
systemctl status rsyslog
```

you should see lines including something like

```
   Active: active (running) since ...
 Main PID: 738 (rsyslogd)
```

You can send the USR1 signal to this numbered process to toggle debug. In this case it would be:

```
sudo kill -USR1 738
```

By default, I think the debug output should be on stdout, which on my Fedora systemd is directed to `/dev/null` for rsyslogd, so this may not help.
I don't have CentOS but it may be similar.
You can look at the systemd unit with:

```
systemctl cat rsyslog
```

In my case this includes the lines:

```
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/sysconfig/rsyslog
StandardOutput=null
```

If this is your case, you can add options to file `/etc/sysconfig/rsyslog` such as:

```
RSYSLOG_DEBUGLOG=/tmp/rsyslogdebug
```

and then restart rsyslogd and try to signal it again to toggle debug.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

When opening `/etc/sysconfig/rsyslog`  I see the following comment ->

# Options for rsyslogd
# Syslogd options are deprecated since rsyslog v3.
# If you want to use them, switch to compatibility mode 2 by "-c 2"
# See rsyslogd(8) for more details

Anyhow, I tried to `export RSYSLOG_DEBUGLOG=/tmp/rsyslogdebug` , but it did not work as the file is not created.

Cheers!

Comment: `/etc/sysconfig/rsyslog` is not read by the shell, but by systemd. You cannot use the word `export` in the line `RSYSLOG_DEBUGLOG=/tmp/rsyslogdebug`. The file will only be created when you signal the process with `kill -USR1`.